# Android Kotlin Widget animate a vector xml image in listview

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, imageview

This is the effect I would like to have:

[image]

I have the following image:

[image]

I have to use this image (loading.xml) in a widget specifically it would be an element of the listview, I have to animate it as seen in the gif.

This is the code I use:

```kotlin
override fun getViewAt(position: Int): RemoteViews? {
        val remoteView = RemoteViews(context!!.packageName, R.layout.list_row)
        val listItem = listItemList[position]

        if (listItem.reached!!)
            remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.iv_circle, R.drawable.check)
        else
            remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.iv_circle, R.drawable.loading)
        return remoteView

}
```

list_row.xml

```xml
...
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_circle"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/loading" />
...
```

loading.xml

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="16dp"
    android:height="16dp"
    android:viewportWidth="16"
    android:viewportHeight="16">
    <path
        android:fillAlpha="0.2"
        android:fillColor="#F5AF45"
        android:pathData="m8,1.5a6.5,6.5 0 1 0 0,13a6.5,6.5 0 0 0 0,-13zm-8,6.5a8,8 0 1 1 16,0a8,8 0 0 1 -16,0z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#F5AF45"
        android:pathData="m7.25,0.75a0.75,0.75 0 0 1 0.75,-0.75a8,8 0 0 1 8,8a0.75,0.75 0 0 1 -1.5,0a6.5,6.5 0 0 0 -6.5,-6.5a0.75,0.75 0 0 1 -0.75,-0.75z" />

</vector>
```

I tried looking in the documentation:

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/drawable-animation#kotlin

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable

But I haven't found a way to animate it.

I think that even a rotation of the image is enough to get the result.

But I think it should be done only on the xml side, because the `kotlin` code side for the widgets is very limited.

Image I need to animate is in a `listview`.

See code above `getViewAt()` to see how the image is inserted.

Can you give me a hand?